# Suggestions for order of annotations in PHP

Tags: php, annotations

I currently use such order of annotations:

Code 1:

```
/**
 * sets elements for main (top), secondary (sub1) level and tertiary (sub2) level;
 * prevents sharing of content with previous instances
 *
 * @param string $TopElement
 * @param string $SubElement1
 * @param string $SubElement2
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws MarC_Exception if top element was not set
 * @throws MarC_Exception if sub1 element was not set
 * @throws MarC_Exception if sub2 element was not set
 * @throws MarC_Exception if all elements were set the same
 */
public function __construct($TopElement="", $SubElement1="", $SubElement2="")
{
 ...
}
```

Code 2:

```
/**
 * elements used for creation of code
 *
 * @static
 * @var array
 */
protected $Elements = array();
```

Code 3:

```
/**
 * @package ...
 *
 * @author ...
 * @copyright ...
 *
 * @license ...
 *
 * generation of advanced select menu
 */
```

At this time i don't use all annotations (probably all I use you can see in codes above).

And I wonder if in php is any suggested (preffered) order of annotations - or it is free matter of programmer (and then this question will be useless).

Comment: It won't have any impact on the execution of your program, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: as tom points out, it varies according to the standards you're trying to follow.  the psr survey didn't cover annotations and having some level of psr compliance is pretty commonly accepted, so annotation order isn't a major concern. out of the more commonly used annotations `var`, `param`, and `return` var is usually by itself, param usually comes before return.  you'll see `throws` occasionally, but it isn't used enough have something that sticks in my mind for position. `@method` is used to document magic methods for code completion, aside from those you only need what reads them needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR; It's a free matter**

PHP coding standards differ on this. The best I can suggest is to pick a coding standard you like and run PHP CodeSniffer (https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) against it and see what it suggest. Some coding standards require they be in a specific order and a specific spacing to your docblock annotations. Others are more relaxed and make no suggestions about docblock annotations what-so-ever.

To get PHP Code Sniffer:

```
$ curl -OL https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcs.phar
$ php phpcs.phar -h
$ php phpcs.phar --standard=[STANDARD_CHOICE] /path/to/project
```

Some coding standards you might want to consider:

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html
- http://pear.php.net/manual/en/rfc.header-comments.php

If you're worried about a document generators (like [phpDocumentor](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html)) not being able to parse the docblock annotations, you can always check what annotations they support. I've never had a problem with phpDocumentor complaining about the ordering or formatting though.

As for custom annotations being used by libraries such as [Doctrine](http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html), [Symfony](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-annotations-gets-better) and [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html), I've also never noticed the order having an impact on the parsing and processing.

Comment: As I looked at the first link, I found that I use most of PSR-2 even if I don't know that is any standard,. Simply because most books and internet sources use it too - and if somebody see something (like this) so much used, then he (or she, for ladies) began to using it too. But I ignore some formatting to I could easily read which brackets of all types are matching.